# Is it correct to find ideal engine's efficiency using celsius scale?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine, efficient-energy-use

I am solving a problem from my book which asks to calculate the maximum efficiency of an engine whose hot body is at temperature 300°C and cold body is at 25°C. Using 1- Tc/Th, I got efficiency equals to 0.916 but my book says that it is 0.479. Then I tried calculating this after converting the temperature into kelvins and got a correct answer. Why didn't the author used temperature in celsius?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In thermodynamics
$$e=1-\frac{T_c}{T_h}$$
is the definition of absolute temperature.

Hence by definition you have to use the absolute temperature scale to obtain the efficiency.

Comment: Definition of Abs Temperature? How?

Comment: $T_c/T_h=1-e$. So for example, if the efficiency is $0.4$, $T_c/T_h=0.6$.

Comment: OK, it happens this way but I don't understand how this expression defines absolute temperature? And what do you mean by definition of absolute temperature?

Comment: It defines absolution temperature up to a scale, which is fixed by setting the triple point of water to be $273.16$ exactly.

Comment: So tell me your definition of absolute temperature.

Comment: Wikipedia: Absolute temperature of an object is the temperature on a scale where 0 is taken as absolute zero.

Comment: Please read wiki Thermodynamic temperature --> Definition of thermodynamic temperature. It is defined by the efficiency of Carnot engine!!

Comment: Yes, it's there.